# Does Blender internal render have limited gains from using better hardware?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, hardware

I have a plan to rent a powerful computer for an animation project to make Blender Internal rendering faster. But I heard that Internal won´t get significantly faster (at least not at the same scale as Cycles). Is it truth?

My computer: Intel Core i7-2600 CPU 3,40 GHz / 12GB Ram / NVIDIA GeForce GT 440